# Why is jQuery.val returning an array instead of a string in Internet Explorer 7 (IE7)?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to grab the value from the following select element. Say the user selects the first option.

```
<select class="your-class" type="text">
    <option value='one'>One</option>
    <option value='two'>Two</option>
    <option value='three'>Three</option>
</select>
```

The javascript:

```
$("select.your-class").val()
//returns ["one"] in IE7, returns "one" in other browsers
```

Why is IE7 returning an array, instead of a single string? This isn't a select multiple element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is the `type` attribute that seems to have been erroneously added to the `select` element (maybe it was originally a text `input` element and it was switched to a `select`)?. Remove the attribute to resolve the issue.

Under the covers, jQuery is using the following boolean to determine if your `select` element is a select one (the standard select box) or a select multiple (select element with the multiple attribute).

```
var IsSelectOne = elem.type === "select-one" || elem.selectedIndex < 0;
```

Setting the `type` attribute overrides the default value of `'select-one'` in IE7, which causes this boolean to be false. Since the boolean is false, this tells jQuery that you have a select-multiple element, and it provides you with an array, instead of a single string.